# Is there a way to capture all FormClosed event in C# within an application automatically?

Tags: c#

I would like to centralize code handler for all FormClosed Event, is there a way to be notified automatically by all forms that are closing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subscribe your event handler after you instantiate the form. i.e. use +=

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Craft
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var f = new Form2();            
            f.FormClosing += ClosingMonitorer;
            f.Show();

            var g = new Form3();
            g.FormClosing += ClosingMonitorer;
            g.Show();
        }

        void ClosingMonitorer(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {            
            MessageBox.Show((sender as Form).Text + " is closing");
        }



    }
}
```

[EDIT: or you can use extension methods to simplify the event subscription process]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Craft
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var f = new Form2();
            f.Show(ClosingMonitorer);            


            var g = new Form3();
            g.Show(ClosingMonitorer);

        }

        void ClosingMonitorer(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show((sender as Form).Text + " is closing");
        }



    }

    public static class Helper
    {
        public static void Show(this Form f, FormClosingEventHandler feh)
        {
            f.FormClosing += feh;
            f.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Subclass `Form` and in the constructor hook up some function to the `FormClosed` event of itself? Something like the following:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm(FormClosedEventHandler handler) : base()
    {
        this.FormClosed += handler;
    }
}
```

And then just use `MyForm` instead of `Form` as your baseclass for all your forms.

**EDIT:** If you've got some static function somewhere that you want to use as a handler for all `FormClosed` events, then you can of course use:

```
    public MyForm() : base()
    {
        this.FormClosed += Program.MyFormClosedHandler;
    }
```

But this is a little bad (hard to test, see dependency injection), and you can use constructor chaining to achieve the same thing anyway.

Comment: Hello good solution, I don't know why it works for me when I create a simple example but it doesn't seem to work on my real world app, will have to investigate why.

Comment: Have you changed all the forms in app to use `MyForm` or whatever you called it insteaed of `Form`?

Answer (score -2):

There isn't an easy way that I am aware of, but if you want to learn some new techniques you could do it with aspect-oriented programming.

Comment: Extending the Form object won't help you with Forms which are not part of your application (OpenFileDialog for instance)

Comment: Why is this a comment on your own answer and not mine? As for needing to handle this case, let the original author say if this is a concern for him. If it is, then you start to dig into message loop filters which will handle your case. But it's a little overkill if you don't need to handle every single little form like common dialogs and message boxes.